# Employment rate among people taking antipsychotics by country

Tags: data-request, medical, demographics

Is there any data on the employment rate among people taking antipsychotics by country?

Given the debilitating effects of these drugs, I would expect them to be close to zero almost everywhere.

Not to mention that most of these people will be confined to bloody mental hospitals.

Comment: I noticed your related questions have gone unanswered, so I'm curious. Have you been able to find *any* data about users of antipsychotics? It seems like this kind of data would be *highly* regulated, if collected at all.

Comment: The truth is that the psychiatric system keeps their users isolated by isolating then, drugging them with drugs that will sedate them to the point where they cannot get it of bed even speak or think, and debilitates their mind. The psychiatric system tries to keep is wrongdoings as invisible as possible.

Comment: There is a Facebook group called "Speak Out Against Psychiatry", but I couldn't find any data there, and I did not have the strength to find anything on the internet. Not sure where to look, any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: A group that's opposed to psychiatry might have plenty of individual anecdotes (eg "such-and-such happened to my mother"), but the people with access to quantitative data will be inside the psychiatric profession. Try looking for articles in medical and psychiatric journals - there are surely some medical processionals who are concerned about such issues, and have made some effort to research them.

Comment: I also recommend keeping your language neutral and open-minded, and avoiding revealing your agenda. Eg, your first sentence ("Is there any data ... by country.") is perfectly neutral. Your second sentence ("Given the debilitating effects...everywhere.") starts to hint at an agenda. After reading your final sentence ("Not to mention...bloody mental hospitals."), a member of the psychiatric profession might hesitate to get involved, even if they privately agree with your assessment of the psychiatric system.

Comment: Then again, most patients will be confined, and unable to speak up, let alone get involved. It's a tragedy.